# Node - Broadcasting to specific clients with WebSockets/ws

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am developing an application where I would like to set up a system with a web socket system that supports namespacing.  I'm using the WebSockets/ws websocket library and I'd like to take a socket.io inspired approach where clients can subscribe to topics and only receive messages sent for that topic but I cannot figure out how to implement this without using socket.io (I'd rather not use it) and I'm currently looking for any guidance that anyone may have on the subject.

Comment: This question is quite open-ended - at what point are you having problems? You need to implement a protocol for subscription, and then when you want to broadcast, look up which clients are subscribed.

Comment: I apologize that it is quite open-ended.  I didn't quite know how I wanted to word it.  I have the websocket server implemented and now I just need to implement the subscription protocol and I am unsure of where to begin with that.